# Сравнение строк в Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, строки

У меня есть класс упорядоченное бинарное дерево в свойстве data я храню данные типа id, чтобы дерево могла хранить любые данные.

При создании нового узла я сравниваю значения ([tmp.data compare:Node.data]) и в зависимости от этого иду по левой ветке или правой.

Вот такой пример я добавляю корень @"6", а затем добавляю узел с данными @"12" и он идет по левой ветке. Я понимаю, что 1 < 6, но строка вторая вроде длинее и должна идти в право.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Длину строки можно сравнивать так:

```
NSString *a = @"a";
NSString *b = @"bb";
if (b.length > a.length) {
// true
}
```

По значениям строки сравниваются так:

```
NSString *a = @"a";
NSString *b = @"bb";
if ([a isEqualToString:b]) {
    // false
}
```

Comment: вот у меня в узле хранится data типа id, т.е. не факт, что там будет строка.
Я сравниваю методом compare, который возвращает NSComparisonResult

Comment: @DaskOFF перед сравнением всегда надо к нужному типу приводить
`NSObject *obj;`
`NSString *myString = obj;`
`[myString isEqualToString @"some string"]`

Comment: т.е. я не могу задать какой-то обищий тип сравнения который будет работать со всеми типами, но например, придется в своих типах переопределить какой-то метод?

Comment: и лучше проверить тип перед сравнением `[obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]`